# Launcher applications "shadow" remains where it was when mouse hovered over it

Tags: launcher, startup, conky

### The background:

I recently installed `conky` and configured it a little bit using some google search and some [posts on Google+](https://plus.google.com/108191085553501782152/posts/NeQc3fkna3m), which I don't think is the root cause of the problem below. I wrote a 1-line script

```
conky -c script_path
```

to run conky at start-up and added that script to "Start-up Applications".

### The problem:

- Whenever I log on, the Launcher appears at log-in screen, which was not the case before I did this.
- The main problem is the "shadow" of applications locked to the `launcher` remain when I hover the mouse over the launcher. I know its difficult to imagine what I am saying, so I have included an image which describes my problem, please have a careful look over the image.

[image: The shadow of applications remain where it were before mouse hovered over it]

### Specifications:

I use the following softwares:

- Ubuntu 12.10 64-bit
- Unity 6.12.0
- Conky 1.9.0
- HP 630 with 500 GB HDD and 4 GB DDRM, no graphics card

I love to play around, so please feel free to express your opinions as to what has to be done.

**P.S.:** When I try to log-in through `gnome-shell`, I can see the launcher on the left, which I feel is unusual, though it is not "functional", meaning, clicking on the `applications` do not open them.

Comment: What have you tried to unlock the shadow effect? Why don't you disabled the script at the login and see what happens?

Comment: I haven't tried anything as I have no idea what causes this. I won't be able to run conky at start-up if I disable the script, which would not bring the desktop I have configured, which is not what I want.

Comment: If you want to solve your problem, you must know *what* is causing your problem. If you stop the script for a while and the problem is gone, then you have yo see what to do with the script. It doesn't mean that you have to delete the script, maybe with some configuration is solved.

Comment: Also, do you have [Ubuntu Tweak](http://ubuntu-tweak.com/) installed in your system? With this software you can set the *panel opacity* effect.

Comment: Ya, so I removed the script from "Start-up Applications", which causes the desktop to remain the same(the appearance is the same), but conky does not start-up, so the desktop is no more "dynamic" giving statistics about the RAM, net, CPU, Disk usage and the time too does not change. But the "shadow" effect remains as before.

Comment: @Lucio: I installed Ubuntu Tweak, I tried to increase the opacity and yes it does "hide" my problem, though it does not actually "solve" it. Thanks, it could just be considered a solution, though I am looking about for an elegant one :)

Comment: @Lucio: Hope the answer below has helped understand my problem and stupidity :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone, I could just figure out what was wrong. I had just messed with my `wallpaper`, which had the `Launcher` to its left, which caused the `"shadow"`. I changed the `wallpaper` which made me realize my stupidity. Wish I could just delete this question, but just in case, someone else may find himself/herself in this situation again. The `Launcher` is fine now! :)